# DockPanel sizing issue

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

I have a problem with the `DockPanel` component. When i resize the panel I don't want the horizontal `ScrollBar` to appear, but instead I want the left content to be resized also at the cost to lose some content. What I want to achieve in fact is that the right content of the `DockPanel` is always visible, avoiding using the horizontal scrollbar to show it.
Hope i was clear!
This is the code: (this dataTemplate goes inside a listview)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Voce}" x:Name="templateVoce">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanelVoce" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Name="labelCodiceVoce" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Voce.Voce}" Text="{Binding Path=Voce.Id}" Width="40" />
                    <TextBlock Name="labelDescrizioneVoce" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Voce.Voce}" Text="{Binding Path=Voce.Voce}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="500" />
                    <TextBlock Name="labelDescrizioneNature" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Voce.Voce}" Text="{Binding Path=ListaNature, Converter={StaticResource listaNatureConverter}}"/>
                    <Expander Name="expander1" Expanded="expander1_Expanded" Collapsed="expander1_Collapsed" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="25" />
                    <TextBox Name="txtValoreVoce" PreviewKeyDown="txtValoreVoce_PreviewKeyDown" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="False" GotFocus="txtValoreVoce_GotFocus" PreviewTextInput="txtValoreVoce_PreviewTextInput_1" AllowDrop="False" Loaded="txtValoreVoce_Loaded"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.VMPadre.IsModifica, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=src:InserimentoVoci, AncestorLevel=1}}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="{Binding Path=Valore, StringFormat=N0}" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="{Binding Path=Valore, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBox.Style>
                        <TextBox.InputBindings>
                            <!--Disable Paste-->
                            <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand"
                        Key="V"
                        Modifiers="Control" />
                        </TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBlock Name="lblPiuMeno" Margin="0,-5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                    <Image Name="imgMulti" Source="/ClientConfidi;component/Immagini/112_Plus_Orange.ico" Margin="1" Visibility="Collapsed" ToolTip="La voce presenta nature opzionali" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <Image Name="imgWarning" Source="/ClientConfidi;component/Immagini/Annotate_Warning.ico" Margin="1" Visibility="Collapsed" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </DockPanel>
                <ContentControl Name="controlExpander" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.VMPadre.IsModifica, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=src:InserimentoVoci, AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

before the critical point of resizing:
[image: before the critical point of resizing]
After the critical point of resing:

[image: after the critical point of resing]
I want the text higlighted to be trimmed instead of hide the expander arrow, that must be always to the right.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! the trick is putting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` in the listview's XAML definition

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps use a Grid instead of a DockPanel. A DockPanel is pretty much a quick grid, and you get much more freedom with a Grid.

I'd use four columns; auto, * auto, and auto, respectively.
Then, to make sure the columns line up in the ListView, add the IsSharedSizeScope property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx

Because the second column's width is set to *, the grid will resize that instead of the columns with width set to auto. You could alternatively set the other columns to a set size.

Comment: it doesn't work... maybe I don't know where to add the IsSharedSizeScope property. changing the dockpanel to a grid the structure is this: `<DataTemplate><StackPanel><Grid></Grid></StackPanel></DataTemplate>`

Comment: Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" should go in the ListBox element. And then you would have to name your ColumnDefinitions, such as <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn"/>

Comment: Sorry but in these days I couldn't try your code, until today.I added the SharedSizeScope to the listview, but adding the SharedSizeGroup will result in a behaviour where resizing horizontaly the listview the content doesn't resize at all...

Comment: Edit: If i remove the SharedSizeGroup of the second column (the one with the * width) the content resize in the same way it resized before adding the sharedsizeproperty (the images in the question). I can't get rid of this problem :(